# input and print array in C

Tags: c

Why this code doesn't print the full array.How to correct the code or improve to print the full array

```
int main(void) {
    float value[MAX], a;
    int bit, i;
    int group[10];

    bit = 0;

    do {
        scanf("%f", &a);
        value[bit] = a;
        bit++;
    } while (a == '\n');

    for (i = 0; i < bit; i++)
        printf("%f", value[i]);
}
```

Comment: Use the back-tick for code shown inline with your regular text. Use 4 spaces at the beginning of each line for *block* formatting of code. Also try and make sure your indenting is consistent and readable.

Comment: The variable `f` is a floating point variable. It will almost never be equal to the character `'\n'`.

Comment: `(a=='\n')` is wrong. Please show an example of input and expected and actual output

Comment: thanks for your advice i kind of new at stakoverflow.

Comment: "*... doesn't print the full array*" Does the print anything at all?

Comment: You should avoid `do { … } while (…)` loops whenever possible.  You should always test the result from `scanf()`.  You can do that with `while (scanf("%f", &a) == 1) { value[bit++] = a; }` where the braces are optional.  This will stop reading reliably when you encounter EOF or a letter or other character that can't be floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

Change the stop condition of your reading from 
while(a=='\n');
to some int/float value.
As mentioned by someprogrammerdude, variable "a" never be equal to '\n'.

Comment: And it needs to be `} while( a != .... );` you want to continue reading numbers while you haven't entered the stop value.  And you probably don't have wanted to store the stop value in the array (which the current code will have done). And performing equality/inequality tests on `float`s is never a good idea.

Comment: How does this Answer help?